# How to implement WPF user control that displays images databound to a decimal number

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Normally I can work out which control I can template to achieve something in WPF but I now have a requirement which I am not really sure how to approach.

What I would like to do is have a column in the datagrid that is databound to a decimal property **TruckLoads**. I also have a small image of a truck.

If the value is 1 I would like to display 1 truck image. If the value is 2.5 I would like to display the image 2.5 times where the 3rd image would only be half the truck.

How would I go about implementing something like this - is it a new user control - can I style an existing control?

Comment: What is MAX number of TruckLoads or it could change in future? Perhaps it is 3 so you can hard code some control layout and switch it using DataTemplateSelector, but if it could be 10 and more you have to use some ItemsControl where single item == 0.5 of truck load so 1 image per item would be displayed

Comment: Do you have the 3 images..? could you add them as a Resource..? and from that just assign the Image to the Image control prior to rendering or binding..?

Comment: The value cannot be hardcoded and I would need to deal with the situation of 0.2 - 1/5 image 0.333 - 1/3 image etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to make a control which will have a dynamic width. Its width would be:

```
controlWidth = imageWidth * numberOfTrucks;
```

then add a background to this control with tiled truck image. Truck will be displayed required number of times.

TruckDisplay.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.TrucksDisplay"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="truck.gif" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,40,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TruckDisplay.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class TrucksDisplay
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof (double), typeof (TrucksDisplay), new PropertyMetadata(DefaultValueChanged));

    private static void DefaultValueChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var trucksDisplay = (TrucksDisplay) dependencyObject;
        trucksDisplay.grid.Width = 40*trucksDisplay.Value;
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public TrucksDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Usage (mainWindow.xaml):

```
<StackPanel>
    <WpfApplication1:TrucksDisplay Value="2" />
    <WpfApplication1:TrucksDisplay Value="2.5" />
    <WpfApplication1:TrucksDisplay Value="3" />
    <WpfApplication1:TrucksDisplay Value="6" />
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image: Trucks]

Please note that I had an image with width=40 and height=30 so I hardcoded these values in several places. It is pretty easy to make it dynamic too to allow specifying an image too.

Comment: fantastic that is exactly what I was looking for. There are so many different ways of doing things in WPF that is sometimes hard to see the wood for the trees. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a `Converter` that implements `IValueConverter`, so you will and in method `Convert()` you will pass float, and convert it to an image in your case.

Your XAML will look something like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path="TruckLoad",Converter={StaticResource TrucksImageConverter}}" />
```

Your `Convert` method will look something like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)   
{
     var trucks = (float)value;


     if (trucks == 1)
         return new BitmapImage("Resource File Path");
     else if (trucks == 2.5)
         return new BitmapImage("Resource File for 2.5 value");
     else if (trucks == 3)
         return new BitmapImage("Resource File for 3 trucks value");
     else
         return null;
}
```

Comment: I was looking into doing it dynamically rather than returning images based on the value. The value converter might be part of the solution although am not sure how to make the image repeat and size.

Comment: Returning images based on value is 'doing it dynamically'. In converter you are free to generate an image if you like, or use an embedded resource.

Comment: @Nikola, by dynamically I meant that I would only have 1 bitmap image representing 1 truck and based on the value in TruckLoads I would display that many truck images with the last Truck image potentially being partial. I would not want to store a embedded resource to represent every combination of truck load.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean decimal property not decimal int property.   You could use a `ListBox` that you send an Array or List of images to.  How you make that last image partial I will leave to you.  I think you could crop a canvas.   I use this approach to display some very large text files where I break on CR LF and send a List < String > to the `ListBox` for virtualiztion and it works great.  To the user it looks like a single text document but a very large document is still fast.